# How to find all commits(files&comments) by a person in cvs

Tags: find, cvs

Looking to get a list of all the files (commit comments would be nice too) of a user in cvs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cvs log -t -wJellyJoe
```

Answer (score 18):

Use the following command to list all commits by a specific user:

```
cvs -q log -N -S -wuser dir/
```

`-N` Do not list tags.
`-S` Do not print name/header if no revisions selected.
`-w[logins]` Only list revisions checked in by specified logins.

Watchout! The order of the switches matters.

For more options and help use:

```
cvs -H log
```

(Listing of switches above taken from this command's output).

Comment: I believe there is no space on the username it is 'cvs -q log -N -S -wuser dir/'

Comment: How can I check this in windows?

Answer (score 11):

```
cvs history -u user -c -D 2009-01-20
cvs history -u user -l -c -D 2009-01-20
```

first line to view all changes by user since specified date
second line lists only the last change, so you get each file only once, even if it has been changed several times.

Comment: Thanks, this one "cvs history -u user -l -c" worked great!

Answer (score 5):

```
cvs history -a -c  -D 2009-01-20
```

to review all commits by all users since 2009-01-20

Comment: He specifically asked about one person commits

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! Even though it doesn't answer the thread question, it answers my concern ;) /thumbup

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick oneliner that will give you a list of every file, followed by changes in that user and the first line of comment from that user.

```
cvs log | egrep -A 1 'Working file|username'
```

Output will look like:

```
Working file: bin/scriptname
head: 1.14
--
date: 2008/01/01 15:15:30;  author: username; state: Exp; lines +3 -2
First line of checkin comment will appear here.
```

This is a quick and dirty one liner, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use external tools, such as [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/), which lets you input queries using web forms. The output is also formatted nicely in the web browser.